# Angularfire2, startAfter() not working for pagination

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

According to the firebase docs, this is how to do it:

```
var first = db.collection("cities")
        .orderBy("population")
        .limit(25);

return first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
  // Get the last visible document
  var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
  console.log("last", lastVisible);

  // Construct a new query starting at this document,
  // get the next 25 cities.
  var next = db.collection("cities")
          .orderBy("population")
          .startAfter(lastVisible)
          .limit(25);
});
```

But the problem is that I see no way of using the get function or even using `snapshotChanges()` to get the length then minus it to be used as a reference for the next get. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Update:

I tried manually inputting the index but to no avail as it returned an array with no data.

```
   getNewsCollectionNext() {
    this.newsCollectionRef = this.afDB.collection('news', ref => 
    ref.where('news_is_deleted', '==', false).orderBy('news_timestamp_post_created', 'desc')
    .startAfter(1));
    this.newsCollection = this.newsCollectionRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as News;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
    return this.newsCollection;
   }
```

While this one returns 3 items

```
   getNewsCollection() {
    this.newsCollectionRef = this.afDB.collection('news', ref => 
    ref.where('news_is_deleted', '==', false).orderBy('news_timestamp_post_created', 'desc'));
    this.newsCollection = this.newsCollectionRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as News;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );
    return this.newsCollection;
    // console.log(this.newsList);
   }
```

Update 2: I made the 'next' function work!

tl;dr: So what I did was to unwrap the doc 
payload and changed my observable type to any to prevent conflicts :)
So here's my code in the service

```
  getNewsCollection() {
    this.newsCollectionSubscription = this.newsService.getNewsCollection().
    subscribe(newsCollection => {
      this.newsCollection = newsCollection;
      console.log('t2est',newsCollection[newsCollection.length - 1].doc);
      if(newsCollection){
        this.snapshot = newsCollection[newsCollection.length - 1].doc;
      }

    });
  }
  getNextNewsCollection() {
    this.newsCollectionSubscription = this.newsService.getNextNewsCollection(this.snapshot).
    subscribe(newsCollection => {
      this.newsCollection = newsCollection;
      // console.log('t2est',newsCollection[1].doc);
      console.log(newsCollection);
    });
  }
```

On my news-card.component.ts

```
  getNewsCollection() {
    this.newsCollectionSubscription = this.newsService.getNewsCollection().
    subscribe(newsCollection => {
      this.newsCollection = newsCollection;
      console.log('t2est',newsCollection[newsCollection.length - 1].doc);
      if(newsCollection){
        this.snapshot = newsCollection[newsCollection.length - 1].doc;
      }

    });
  }
  getNextNewsCollection() {
    this.newsCollectionSubscription = this.newsService.getNextNewsCollection(this.snapshot).
    subscribe(newsCollection => {
      this.newsCollection = newsCollection;
      // console.log('t2est',newsCollection[1].doc);
      console.log(newsCollection);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the the following HTML page that shows (in pure Javascript) how to modify the `query` in order to display the documents page by page.

You can download it to a local folder/directory, adapt the config object and open it with a browser. Clicking on the button will display, in the Console, the documents 3 by 3.

Note that, in this simple POC, there is no error handling when the pagination reaches the end of the collection.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="myBtn">Display next subset</button>

        <script>
            document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
                displayNextPaginationSubset();
            });
          // Initialize Firebase
          var config = {
            apiKey: "....",
            authDomain: "....",
            databaseURL: "....",
            projectId: "...."
          };
          firebase.initializeApp(config);

          var db = firebase.firestore();
          var query = db.collection("cities")
              .orderBy("population")
              .limit(3);

          function displayNextPaginationSubset() {

              query.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {

                  documentSnapshots.forEach(function(doc) {
                      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                  });


                  // Get the last visible document
                  var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
                  console.log("last", lastVisible);

                  // Construct a new query starting at this document,
                  // get the next 3 cities.
                  query = db.collection("cities")
                          .orderBy("population")
                          .startAfter(lastVisible)
                          .limit(3);
              });

          }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But is there really no way to do that in angularfire2? Sad

Comment: Sorry, I don't know angular so I cannot help you anymore.

Comment: Note that actually it is just a matter of updating the `query` variable after each call to `get()`.