# AngularFirestore - limit and startAfter not working

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to build a webpage with `AngularFireStore` as my data store. In order to enable infinite scrolling, I am trying to query the store with `limit` and `startAfter` functionality of `AngularFireStore`.

For some reason, I am not able to get it working. The `limit` functionality is not working as expected as it returns values greater / lesser than the actual limit, and there are duplicate values as well

I have searched and tried few approaches ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536684/firestore-angularfire2-pagination-query-items-by-range-startafterlastvis), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736962/angularfire2-startafter-not-working-for-pagination?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2012)). But nothing works.

Here is what I have tried:

**crudService.ts :**

```
readNextPost(cursor){
    return this.firestore.collection('MyCollection',
                                      ref => ref.orderBy('date', 'desc')
                                                .startAfter(cursor)
                                                .limit(10)
                                                ).snapshotChanges();
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
mapResponseToObject(data) {
  return {
    id: data.payload.doc.id,
    doc: data.payload.doc
  }
}

setLastPost(data) {
  this.lastFetchedPost = data[data.length - 1].doc;
}

fetchNextPosts() {
    this.crudService.readNextPost(this.lastFetchedPost).subscribe(data =>{
      let nextPost = data.map(this.mapResponseToObject)
      this.allPosts = [...this.allPosts, ...nextPost];
      this.setLastPost(nextPost);
    })
  }
```

`readNextPost` returns values less than `10` although there are more than that in the store,  and some times returns more than `10`, which has values that were  fetched earlier.
This causes duplicate data visible in the webpage.

As a newbie to both `AngularFireStore` and `Angular 10`, I am stuck at this issue for several hours. Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the subscribe:

```
  this.firestore.collection('MyCollection',
                                  ref => ref.orderBy('date', 'desc')
                                            .startAfter(cursor)
                                            .limit(10)
                                            ).get()
                       .subscribe(response => {
                        for (const item of response.docs) {
                            console.log(item.data());
                          }
                    });;
```

I think snapshotChanges is a stream of "Changes", not the full result of the query.I'm assuming that means changes to the result of the query but the docs aren't too clear:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges